# Me da resultado 0 y no se como arreglarlo

Tags: c++

Tengo que hacer un programa que me devuelva el doble del valor, con funciones, soy bastante nuevo y las funciones me cuestan mucho todavía, imagino que algo me debo estar salteando en la parte del valor y la cuenta, y necesito algún consejo más para saber como hacer muchos de estos ejercicios porque siempre me faltan pequeños detalles que me salteo, gracias.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int EsMultiplode(int numero);

int main() {
    int n, doble;
    cout << "Digite valor para devolver el doble: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    doble = EsMultiplode(n * 2);
    cout << doble << endl;
    return 0;
}

int EsMultiplode(int numero) {
    int valor;
    valor = valor * 2;
    return valor;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para la solución de tu código es la siguiente, lo primero vamos a hablar de la función que has creado, para que este bien, sería de la siguiente manera.

```
int EsMultiplode(int numero) {
    return numero * 2; // Para ahorrar codigo es mas simple no poner ninguna
                       // variable y directamente retornar el
                       // numero multiplicado por 2
}
```

El resto que sería el main sería así:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int EsMultiplode(int numero);

int main() {
    int n, doble;
    cout << "Digite valor para devolver el doble: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    // Aquí simplemente debes remover el n*2, tu le vas a pasar por parametro el
    // numero a multiplicar, la funcion ya se encargara de hacer lo que tu
    // quieres.
    doble = EsMultiplode(n);
    cout << doble << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Encuentro 2 errores en tu código:

Primer error:

```
doble = EsMultiplode(n*2);// estas mandando el doble del número leido
```

Como debería ser

```
doble = EsMultiplode(n);
```

Segundo error:

```
int EsMultiplode (int numero) 
{
int valor; //creas una variable local pero nunca usas el valor que recibes por parámetro (numero)
valor = valor*2;
return valor;
}
```

Como debería ser:

```
int EsMultiplode (int numero)
{   
    return numero*2;
}
```

Entonces tu código completo quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int EsMultiplode (int numero);
int main (){
int n,doble;
    cout<<"Digite valor para devolver el doble: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    doble = EsMultiplode(n);
    cout<<doble<<" es el doble de "<<n<<endl;
        return 0;
}
int EsMultiplode (int numero)
{   
    return numero*2;
}
```